Why is "Perché è" not contracted?
I have not yet seen "Perché è" contracted to "Perch'è", except on the internet. Why does it not contract in the same way as, for instance, "Dov'è"?

Stressed vowels are not removed in contractions. Dove has an unstressed vowel at the end, so dov'è is fine, but perché has a stressed one.
